# How can I change paragraph formatting to \n to put in a textView

Tags: android, formatting

I am writing an Android app and I have lots of texts that will be stored in string arrays and be displayed in a TextView. The texts are currently in Word Documents. Is there a way to replace all the paragraph breaks with \n without doing each one individually? If I copy and paste from the word document there is no formatting that is copied and it will be really tedious to go through all the texts inserting the \n. 
Thanks.

Comment: I think you need Sublime text to help you. Actually most of the text editor has replace function that could help you to do this easily. For example, you might want to first turn on regular expression search, then search for "\n" , then you replace it with "\\n".

Comment: It took me a while to figure out how to use Sublime Text, but I did as you suggested and it worked perfectly. Thanks so much!